# ssh asks for a password even though the key is copied

Tags: linux, ssh

I copied the key to the server, but ssh still asks for the password

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id root@192.168.1.60
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/sp595/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@192.168.1.60's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'root@192.168.1.60'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

maybe this will help:

1.I have another server with which access by the same key works

2.I used to have such access, but at some point it stopped (I didn't change anything). After that, I decided to delete the .ssh folder and create the directory and files again.

Here are the logs:

```
OpenSSH_9.3p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/sp595/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.60 [192.168.1.60] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sp595/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.60:22 as 'root'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/sp595/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:O7LAk4O8AalrA7uXJxKdRbraxESmBUYmrojZ+33DsLw
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/sp595/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.1.60' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/sp595/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:o0Hr2pPlpAOjgzOoqwG1Xyi70rwFxiBb76rk84kcuug
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:o0Hr2pPlpAOjgzOoqwG1Xyi70rwFxiBb76rk84kcuug
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sp595/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Add which steps you had done before, like `eval $(ssh-agent)` and `ssh-add`

Comment: Check if the target machine has file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and it contains your public key. If not, look at the SSH server log, because that's what's missing in this question.

Comment: @RadosławSerba Yes there is a file on the server and it contains the value of my key

Comment: @GillesQuénot updated the question

Comment: Provide authentication logs, that should be better to review. Depending on distro it will be `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: Where is the mandatory `ssh-add` command??? What is the output of `echo ${!SSH*}` ?

Comment: @GillesQuénot why do we need this command? I've always been able to do it without her. How should I prescribe it then? echo ${!SSH*} output: zsh: event not found: SSH

Comment: Try using `bash` the command `echo ${!SSH*} `

Comment: @GillesQuénot this command outputs a void if I run it in bash

Comment: So you don't have executed `eval $(ssh-agent)`... `->[read again my answer]`

Comment: @GillesQuénot I noticed an interesting feature. when I ran eval$(ssh-agent) via zsh in bash when running echo${!SSH*} it didn't give anything, but when I entered eval$(ssh-agent) in bash it output: SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_AUTH_SOCK

Comment: Please provide the relevant lines from your sshd server logs from these login attempts.

Comment: And just for completeness please also show the output of `namei -l /root/.ssh/authorized_keys` from the server.